# How do I initialize an instance of this gem (artii)?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I’m  using this gem, Artii: http://rubydoc.info/gems/artii/1.0.2/frames

I’m trying to initialize with `Artii.new` , but I’m getting an undefined method error.

Is this the right way to initialize an instance of the Artii class?

Any answers appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like artii is a command line program, so after installing the gem you could write in your terminal (not irb)

```
artii 'bla'
```

and will output

```
| |   | |      
| |__ | | __ _ 
| '_ \| |/ _` |
| |_) | | (_| |
|_.__/|_|\__,_|
```

in irb you could use something like, and the output will be the same..

```
artii = Artii::Base.new([])
puts artii.asciify('bla')
```

btw looking at the source seems like artii doesnt work with ruby 1.9.. [link](https://github.com/miketierney/artii/blob/master/lib/artii.rb#L36-41)

Comment: Great answer, got this working.Thank you very much, this was a real help.